# Bokeh: is it possible to change the Coordinate reference systems from bokeh.tile_providers?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to know if it is possible to add a `tile` in `Bokeh` with a different system' reference of the coordinates

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors

output_file("tile.html")

tile_provider = get_provider(Vendors.CARTODBPOSITRON)

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range=(-1000000, 7000000),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(tile_provider)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to look at Goviews library built on top of bokeh and cartopy.

[documentation](http://geoviews.org/user_guide/Projections.html) provides great examples for using different reference systems:

```
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf

from geoviews import opts
from cartopy import crs

gv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')


nyc, beijing = (-74.0, 40.7, 'NYC'), (116.4, 39.9, 'Beijing')
london = (14471.53, 6712008., 'London')

cities_lonlat   = gv.Points([nyc, beijing], vdims='City')
cities_mercator = gv.Points([london], crs=crs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR, vdims='City')

(gv.tile_sources.Wikipedia * cities_lonlat * cities_mercator).opts(
    opts.Points(global_extent=True, width=500, height=475, size=12, color='black'))
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7cYu.png)